# Why does $E(XY)^2 \le E(X^2)E(Y^2)$ fail to hold for complex $X, Y$?

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation

Does the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality hold only for real vectors? Why is that so?

Comment: Not totally familiar with the subject matter, but isn't it just because complex numbers are not ordered? Or did you mean $|E(XY)^2| \leq |E(X^2)E(Y^2)|$.

Comment: What does it mean to say that $x\geq y$ for complex $ x,y$?

Comment: I thought X^2 in this context would be the same as taking the modulus of the complex elements

Comment: You should either edit the Question to say what you misunderstood, or perhaps you will want to delete the Question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This inequality that you have written is valid for real random variables, since you can not compare complex values with each other. As you know the expectation of a complex random variable is still complex, and hence you cannot state the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for complex random variables in this way.

Note that according to Hölder's inequality we can say:

if $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ then for any real or complex random variables $X$ and $Y$:
$E[|XY|]\leq (E[|X|^p])^\frac{1}{p}(E[|Y|^q])^\frac{1}{q}$

hence if you let $p=q=2$, then you have:

$E[|XY|]^2\leq E[|X|^2]E[|Y|^2]$

which you can use for complex random variables.

Note that in this case, the final values which you have, are real values, hence comparison is valid.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for [Hölder inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality). In particular, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, if $XY$ is  $L^1$ integrable, and $X$ and $Y$ are $L^2$ integrable:

$$  \left| E\left[X\overline{Y}\right]\right| \leq E\left[\left|XY\right|\right]
\leq E\left[\left|X\right|^2\right]^{1/2}E\left[\left|Y\right|^2\right]^{1/2}.$$